# adding at the end of a singly-linked list in constant time

Tags: java, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to write a method for adding at the end of a singly linked list in a constant time. I don't know how to assign a pointer to the last node in the list in constant time. This method runs in 0(n):

```
public void insertEnd(Object obj) {
if (head == null) {
  head = new SListNode(obj);
} else {
  SListNode node = head;
  while (node.next != null) {
    node = node.next;
  }
  node.next = new SListNode(obj);
}
size++;
}
```

This is a beginning of my new method:

```
public void addLast(SListNode obj){
  //if the list is empty, the new element is head and tail
  if(tail == null){  
      obj.next = null;
      head = tail = obj;
  }else{   -----> here I'm confused 

  }
}
```

This is my SList class:

```
public class SList {
   private SListNode head;
   private SListNode tail;
   private int size;

   public SList() {
   size = 0;
   head = null;
   tail = null;

}
```

Comment: Maybe store the end of list as field in the class?

Comment: I did that, but how to you actually assign it to the last element ?

Comment: @Frugo, `tail.next = obj;`

Comment: can I get some updates on this thread ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should cover it: (should go in the `else`)

```
tail.next = obj; // have (the current tail).next point to the new node
tail = obj; // assign 'tail' to point to the new node
obj.next = null; // may not be required
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement a [Double Ended Queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-ended_queue) that allow to insert at head or at tail of your List

If your List is empty, both head and tail are null, if it contains one element `head == tail`

```
public void addLast(SListNode obj){
//if the list is empty, the new element is head and tail
if(tail == null){  
  obj.next = null;
  head = tail = obj;
}else{   -----> here I'm confused 
  tail.next = obj;
  tail = obj;
}
```